# Potential employer bidding against themselves - should I be worried?

Tags: job-offer

I went in for an interview a short while ago and was made a provisional offer which I said I'd accept.

A couple of days later I got a phone call saying they are increasing their offer - with no prompting from my end.

This seems odd to me. Why would a company do such a thing and should I be concerned?

Comment: Why do you think you should be concerned? Also, did they give any reasons?

Comment: @Erik They gave a vague reason about me potentially undervaluing myself, but I don't see how that is their concern. I feel it may be of concern to me because they may not put the company's needs first in other situations.

Comment: It's their concern because when you realize you are undervaluing yourself, you might leave. They might also realize that happy and motivated employees are MUCH better for the bottom line than underpaid ones.

Comment: Given your experience and industry, would you have said the original salary was close to the industry standard for your role?

Comment: @Kozaky I actually thought the Original salary was already curving high considering the role and my experience level. That made me extra alert to it, I suppose.

Comment: Another possibility is that people of similar experience in your role already at the company make more than the original offer and they are just heading off any regret and attempts at renegotiation, which gets back to Erik's point.

Comment: Seriously?  Take the money and move on!

Comment: @MisterPositive: Take the money and don't move on!

Comment: @gnasher729 should have said move on with life...

Answer (score 11):

I can see two possible reasons for this behaviour, none of them being a red flag :

1. They fear you'll be hired for more money by another company, now or soon.
2. They have a standard pay for standard profiles, and noticed they made a mistake upon their first offer.

reason 2 is the most likely, and is not a problem : you'll be at company standard. Reason one is even better : it means your profile is hot. Enjoy.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Though a creeping doubt that they may be expecting too much from me I can't escape from.

Comment: Well, all employers expect a lot from their employees.

Comment: Not everybody can be excellent. Expecting otherwise is setting up for disappointment. Anyway, straying from the topic. Good answer.

Comment: @WeckarE. That's what the interviews are for: so you can figure out what kind of person they need and whether it's a job that you'll enjoy and/or excel at. As this answer says an offer increase is not a useful data point to determine that.

Comment: @WeckarE. It's good to know your abilities, but don't fall into the trap of [Imposter Syndrome](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect).

Comment: Or as Joel wrote [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/06/15/whaddaya-mean-you-cant-find-programmers/) it could be part of their hiring strategy.

Comment: @Kempeth : which is a variant of my point 1 : Joel wants to keep you in his firm.

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me some long time ago. Maybe you did exceptionally well in the interview, and somebody decided that they should increase the offer to make it fair considering your qualities, or somebody decided you were so good that they really want you, and increased to offer to make sure you don't go elsewhere. *Or* you might not have been so good after all, but they really need the position filled urgently.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not have to be concerned. You might actually got lucky and found a company with a healthy grasp on the subject of "human capital".

The short-term money you save by underpaying somebody is nothing if weighted against the possible long term negative effects this could have on morale and loyalty.